# Need to compute execution time using data in table in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, aggregate-functions

I am in need of calculating execution time (difference between timestamp) using data from table in Bigquery. This table contains sample data as below:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
|Command Name | Timestamp                        | Status | 
-----------------------------------------------------------
|Command1     | 2022-11-03T19:16:16.767657+05:30 | START  |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|Command1     | 2022-11-03T19:26:16.767657+05:30 | DONE   |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|Command2     | 2022-11-03T19:36:16.767657+05:30 | START  |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|Command2     | 2022-11-03T19:56:16.767657+05:30 | DONE   |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

First column contains the command, second column contains timestamp of the execution of the command and last column contains the respective status.
With this data, the requirement is to calculate the execution time of each of the command which is defined as:

Execution time of command  = Timestamp of command with status as DONE  - Timestamp of command with status as START.

This data is stored in the BigQuery. As I am new to the BigQuery, could anyone please help me achieve this.

Thanks and Regards,
Prafulla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider below query using a window function,

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 'Command1' command, TIMESTAMP '2022-11-03T19:16:16.767657+05:30' timestamp, 'START' status UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Command1' command, '2022-11-03T19:26:16.767657+05:30' timestamp, 'DONE' status UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Command2' command, '2022-11-03T19:36:16.767657+05:30' timestamp, 'START' status UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Command2' command, '2022-11-03T19:56:16.767657+05:30' timestamp, 'DONE' status
)
SELECT command, TIMESTAMP_DIFF(LEAD(timestamp) OVER w, timestamp, SECOND) execution_time
  FROM sample_table QUALIFY status = 'START'
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY command ORDER BY timestamp);
```

or using an aggregation function.

```sql
SELECT command, TIMESTAMP_DIFF(MAX(timestamp), MIN(timestamp), SECOND) execution_time
  FROM sample_table
 WHERE status IN ('START', 'DONE')
 GROUP BY 1;
```

**Query results**

[image]

(Updated) to calculate the average execution time.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  -- same as above
)
SELECT AVG(execution_time) avg_execution_tme FROM (
  SELECT command, TIMESTAMP_DIFF(LEAD(timestamp) OVER w, timestamp, SECOND) execution_time
    FROM sample_table QUALIFY status = 'START'
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY command ORDER BY timestamp)
);
```

Comment: Thanks a million for help on this bro. Query given by you is working like a charm.

Comment: could you please let me know if we can calculate average execution time too for the same set of data?

Comment: @user3523860, sure you can do like  *SELECT AVG(execution_time) avg_execution_time FROM ( .-- put main query above here --  )*.   kindly check the updated answer.